# Change the icon and splash screen of ionic 4

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic4

i'm trying to change the icon and spalsh screen of my ionic 4 project,I did all the necessary steps to make it work, but I got always the old ones, is there any step I skipped, or its a cache problem?

I installed :

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen  
$ npm install @ionic-native/splash-screen
```

and I executed this command :

```
ionic resources --splash
```

but I stille got the default ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use one of the following commands to generate the files.

```
ionic cordova resources
ionic cordova resources ios
ionic cordova resources android
```

Source: https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-resources